# Android Google Map AutoComplete GeoDataAPI giving bounds specific results

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am implementing the search functionality on the google maps. For this I am using the Places.GeoDataApi of google.

But the problem I am facing that it is searching based on the LatLanBounds value.
Currently I am passing sydney specific bounds in below api,so at the time of search its biased towards these bounds and checking syndey specific locations first.

```
private static final LatLngBounds mBounds= new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(-34.041458, 150.790100), new LatLng(-33.682247, 151.383362));

        PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                Places.GeoDataApi
                .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                        mBounds, mPlaceFilter);
```

As per my requirement, Above API should return the result of near by area first. For example, if user is in India and search for something it should return the suggestions related to India on priority and If user in Brazil try to search something API should return the suggestion related to Brazil. I do not know how to pass the dynamic LatLng bounds values based on user current country or location.

your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how can I find LatLngBounds value for Brazil?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is month old question, but I hope my answer will help the OP or somebody else with similar problems.

The answer for main question is pretty straighforward:
Create new **LatLngBounds** ([docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds)) object each time you get information about user location and pass this object as a parameter of **.getAutocompletePredictions**:

```
LatLng sw = new LatLng(SOUTH_WEST_LAT, SOUTH_WEST_LNG);
LatLng ne = new LatLng(NORTH_EAST_LAT, NORTH_EAST_LNG);

LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(sw, ne);

Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint, bounds, null);
```

> These two points, south-west and north-east are opposite corners of the square that makes an area around user's location. This is the bound.

About your second question, in the comment. I suppose you have your user location (eg. from GPS), for example in Brazil, and you need to find the bounds of this location.
To do that, I would use basic Google Places API call (you can try it out in your browser):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Brazil
```

that will return you JSON formatted data about Brazil with field *bounds* in it:

```
"geometry" : {
   "bounds" : {
      "northeast" : {
         "lat" : 42.1282269,
         "lng" : -87.7108162
       },
       "southwest" : {
          "lat" : 42.0886089,
          "lng" : -87.7708629
       }
   },
    ...
}
```

As you can see, these are the north-east and south-west bounds of square in which Brazil lies. You can put them into the LatLngBounds object now.